# How to set up Google Chromium API Keys?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

Recently got Chromium 47.0.2503.0 (Developer Build) Ubuntu 12.04 (32-bit) downloaded and installed, but having a hard time setting up the Chromium API Keys I'm following the  guide on the chromium site [How-tos/api-keys](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/api-keys) I'm having a hard time after choosing the APIs.

Step 7 is the part I'm stuck at.

> Go to the Credentials tab under the APIs & auth tab.
>   Click the blue  Create New Client ID  button in the OAuth section to create an OAuth 2.0 client ID.
>   You want "Installed Application" for the APPLICATION TYPE section
>   You want "Other" for the INSTALLED APPLICATION TYPE section

When ever I create a new client ID and choose OAuth 2.0 client, I don't see this:

> You want "Installed Application" for the APPLICATION
>   TYPE section You want "Other" for the INSTALLED APPLICATION TYPE
>   section

Did I miss a step? or did they make some adjustements to the Google cloud developer console?

Any help will gladly be appreciated.